# Update query that should apply numbers to a text field fail

Tags: vba

I have a simple update query that should apply numbers to a text field, but it keeps dropping the leading zero. Should be 054846, but ends up as 54846. Can't figure out what I'm missing.

```
Dim strsql As String
strsql = "UPDATE [Action]" _
       & "SET [Action] = (" & "054846" & ")"

DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
```

Please help out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the field in the table is defined as a string. But the SQL you have has the number as an integer because you didn't surround the value with single quotes. You will see the issue if you output the SQL string you're trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

Surround number with single qoute '

Dim strsql As String strsql = "UPDATE [Action]" _ & "SET [Action] = '" & "054846" & "' "
 DoCmd.RunSQL strsql